# Using Riemann sum

Tags: calculus

Given the formula 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(i\alpha) = \frac{(\sin(\frac{(n+1)\alpha}{2})\sin(\frac{n\alpha}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})}$$

Use Riemann sum to compute $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin(x)\, dx $$

I have manage to find the length of each subinterval$$\Delta x=\frac{\pi}{2n} $$ and found my $$S_n = \left(\frac{(\sin(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{4n})\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{4n})}\right)(\frac{\pi}{2n})$$

but when n tends to infinity $S_n$ becomes 0 which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\sin((n + 1)\pi/(4n))\sin(\pi/4) \sim \sin^2(\pi/4) = 1/2$$
as $n\to\infty$. What remains to be dealt with is
$${\pi\over 2n\sin(\pi/(4n)}$$
But here we have 
$$\sin(\pi/(4n))\sim {\pi\over 4n}, $$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\pi\over 2n\sin(\pi/(4n)} = {\pi\over 2n/(4n) } = 2 $$
Assembling the evidence, your limit converges to 1, agreeing with direct evaluation of the integral.

Comment: so you are approximating for the first part to $\frac{1}{2}$